# In intellij can one set the "path" environment variable relative to the output root when debugging a java app

Tags: java, intellij-idea

To refine this I spawn an ant task that builds native DLLs and puts them in a "artifact" area relative to the project output directory. So I want to set the path variable for the debug process to contain the path to the DLLs so the java code can load them and do so properly wherever the project folder might lie on any machine

basically to accomplish something like:

${PATH} = ${INTELLIJ_OUTPUT_ROOT}/bin;${PATH}
... spawn java debugger

This because there are multiple copies of builds around on different machines or checked out to different versions of the code for the DLLs all of them work finding the proper resources in their sandboxes for their specific builds without conflict.

Comment: Have you tried to use Ant build script which you can [generate by IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generating-ant-build-file.html)? If there are artifacts configured in project IDE creates Ant tasks for building the artifacts as well. It contains definition of the artifact output directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @alfasin for:

> In the menu choose Run-->Edit configuration
>
> Then go to Environment Variables and you can add PATH and any value you want.

Apparently use of the $PROJECT_DIR$ macro in there is a recent addition in the the latest version - I now have 2018.1 installed.  Before one couldn't use macros in there. :) However if I HAND EDIT the MyRunConfig.xml file in .idea/runConfigurations and put the macro in it works :) :) :).

```
<env name="PATH" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/../build/bin/Win64-VC14-MD-Debug" />
```

Though annoyingly The UI does not show the macro in the editable field only the expanded version.

I will note that if I enter in a value which IS relative to the $PROJECT_DIR$ it will automatically insert the macro which is good but the interface should not hide what is being done.

Answer (score 1):

In the menu choose `Run-->Edit configuration`

Then go to `Environment Variables` and you can add PATH and any value you want.

Comment: Thanks - apparently use of the $PROJECT_DIR$ macro in there is a recent addition in the the latest version. Before one couldn't use them in there. :)

However if I HAND EDIT the MyRunConfig.xml file in .idea/runConfigurations and put the macro in.

      <env name="PATH" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/../build/bin/Win64-VC14-MD-Debug" />

it works fine.  Though annoyingly it does not show the macroo in the editable field in the UI as A MACRO nor does it have a way to see the available macros nor select and place the macro in the field from the UI.

So I have to hand edit the xml file.